# how can I access absolute vertex positions from mesh with armature?

Tags: python, armature, vertices, bmesh

I downloaded an animated mesh in FBX form from mixamo. When I import it to blender, the object looks like this in the outliner:
[image: mixamo data imported in outliner]

I need to access vertex positions of my mesh at every frame of the animation. As far as I understand, blender stores the rest position of the mesh. For rigid objects, I can get the global world transformation matrix and apply it to each vertex. But these have armatures and I can't seem to get the right vertex positions whether I use the BMesh class or just regular meshes with the evaluated dependency graph.

The meshes `Beta_Surface` and `Beta_Joints` both have armature modifiers that, when applied, keep the object in its place.

However, when I try to access the vertex positions, I get positions that are rotated and scaled very big compared to the mesh when it's connected to the armature object. You can see the effect here when I delete the armature object and the surface is no longer constrained by it:
[image: deleting armature]

How do I get the vertex positions from the pose? It's so frustrating because when I export the object to OBJ format or even look at the posed mesh in the viewport, it has the positions I want, so they must be stored somewhere! I have been trying to access these positions for a week with no luck :( I must not be understanding armatures completely.

Thanks in advance for your help.